# "error: 'a' does not name a type" inside class definition

Tags: c++

So I was coding just a basic program that used concept of inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
   public:

    int a;

     a = 100;


};

class derived:public base
{
   public:

   void display()
   {

    cout << "Value of a is " <<a;

   }

};

int main()
{
    derived d;
    d.display();

    return 0;
}
```

error says:

```
error: 'a' does not name a type  
    a = 100;`
```

Please help, what does it mean and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
a = 100;
```

You can't initialize `a` there. You can initialize it in the previous line (assuming C++11 or newer):

```
int a = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not particularly informative for beginners to C++, but the reason for it is that are a number of things that cannot be done within a class or struct definition.   Declaring types, declaring members, or member functions are allowed.   Assigning to a variable or to a class member are not allowed.

A statement that only does an assignment (like `a = 100`) can appear in the body of a function, but not within a class definition (unless in the body of an inline function).

You can assign to a member of a class or struct within an inline member function, such as

```
class base
{
    public:

       int a;

       void some_member_function() {a = 100;};   // inline function definition
};
```

In C++11 and later, it is possible to initialise a member where it is declared.

```
class base
{
    public:

       int a = 100;
};
```

However, although it looks like an assignment (visually similar syntax) it actually is a declaration and initialisation of the `int` member `a` (something different from an assignment).   Without the preceding `int` keyword (or the name of some other appropriate type) the `a = 100` is invalid.     Which, if you think about it, possibly explains why your compiler gives the error message it does - when the compiler sees the token `a` it most often expects to see a type name, but `a` is not a type name.